# List of suspected Malicious patterns

Tags: design-patterns, assembly, antivirus, anti-patterns

I am doing an anti-virus project by disassembling its code and analyzing it.
So I want a list of the Suspected Malicious pattern codes, so I can observe which is suspected and which is not?

So I want a list of suspected patterns only.

Comment: I think you should post a related question on IT Security to get feedback on links to sources other than wikipedia (nothing wrong with that site) on virus patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Very long time ago, a program calling BIOS INT21h ([TSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_Stay_Resident)) points to a suspicious behavior.

BTW, Wikipedia entry for [computer virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) have a lot information about [infection strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Infection_strategies) and [methods to avoid detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Methods_to_avoid_detection).